# Parse JSONArray contains JSONObjects Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift3, xcode8, alamofire

hello i'm new to swift and I have responseJson from alamofire consist of jsonArray contain jsonObjects like this

```
[{"id":"1","name":"person1"},{"id":"2","name":"person2"}]
```

how i can parse it into array of this custom model

```
class Person {
  var name : String
  var id : String
}
```

i've done a much searching but can't find case identical to mine and i can't use Codable because i'm using xcode 8 and not able to upgrade my xcode version to 9 now

I'm getting the response like this

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{ response in
            if(response.result.isSuccess)
            {
                if let jsonarray = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] 
                    {
                      //what to do here ?
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: how are you getting the json object from your url response?

Comment: @ReinierMelian post edited with the request body , i exactly need to know how to get the json object

Comment: you already have the json body, you need to know how to turn it into Persons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let jsonarray = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]]{
    //what to do here ?
    var persons:[Person] = []
    for userDictionary in jsonarray{
        guard let id = userDictionary["id"] as? String, let name = userDictionary["name"] as? String else { continue }
        persons.append(Person(id, name))
    }
    //Persons complete.
}
```

Use `guard else` for the required variables.
If there are additional variables that could be optional, like `var age:Int?` in `Person`, you could do like this:

```
for userDictionary in jsonarray{
    guard let id = userDictionary["id"] as? String, let name = userDictionary["name"] as? String else { continue }
    let age = userDictionary["age"] as? Int
    persons.append(Person(id, name, age))
}
```

Comment: Great ^^ 
that's exactly what i need
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

@Tony,

In **swift4** you can **codable** protocol to parsing the JSON that helps in writing generic code. Suppose if in future requirement came to add dob than its very simple. 
And in **swift3** you can use object mapper class for same.

If you need more help than please let me know.

Comment: Thanks , but i'm already highlighted in my question that i can't use Codable 

And @Sti did exatly what i need :)